# Using texreg (or similar) to produce a regression table for clustered standard error function (cl) output

Tags: r, latex, texreg

I've been using the excellent package `texreg` to produce LaTeX-ready regression tables from fitted model objects, but it doesn't seem to be compatible with various functions that adjust my standard errors for clustering.  Some fake data and code gives an example and an error message below.

Any thoughts on how to get the output that I want (similar to what I get from `texreg`)?

```
x  = rnorm(1000)
IDs = ceiling(seq(from = .1, to = 10,length.out=1000))
s = c(rep(rnorm(1),100),rep(rnorm(1),100),rep(rnorm(1),100),rep(rnorm(1),100),rep(rnorm(1),100),rep(rnorm(1),100),rep(rnorm(1),100),rep(rnorm(1),100),rep(rnorm(1),100),rep(rnorm(1),100))
y = 3*x + 1.5^(IDs)*rnorm(n=1000,sd=s^2)*x + rnorm(1000)*.3
IDs = as.factor(IDs)
d = data.frame(x,IDs,y)
m = lm(y~IDs+x,data=d)
summary(m)

library(texreg)
texreg(m,omit.coef="IDs")

\begin{table}
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{l c }
\hline
            & Model 1 \\
\hline
(Intercept) & $0.12$       \\
            & $(4.50)$     \\
x           & $5.28^{***}$ \\
            & $(1.41)$     \\
\hline
R$^2$       & 0.02         \\
Adj. R$^2$  & 0.01         \\
Num. obs.   & 1000         \\
\hline
\multicolumn{2}{l}{\scriptsize{\textsuperscript{***}$p<0.001$, 
  \textsuperscript{**}$p<0.01$, 
  \textsuperscript{*}$p<0.05$}}
\end{tabular}
\caption{Statistical models}
\label{table:coefficients}
\end{center}
\end{table}

cl   <- function(dat,fm, cluster){
           cluster = as.numeric(cluster)
       attach(dat, warn.conflicts = F)
           library(sandwich)
        library(lmtest)
           M <- length(unique(cluster))
           N <- length(cluster)
           K <- fm$rank
           dfc <- (M/(M-1))*((N-1)/(N-K))
           uj  <- apply(estfun(fm),2, function(x) tapply(x, cluster, sum));
           vcovCL <- dfc*sandwich(fm, meat=crossprod(uj)/N)
           coeftest(fm, vcovCL) }

result = cl(d,m,IDs)
texreg(result,omit.coef="IDs")
```

> Error in (function (classes, fdef, mtable)  :    unable to find an
>   inherited method for function ‘extract’ for signature ‘"coeftest"’

Comment: Did you try following section 5.5 of the package vignette/JSS article [(http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/texreg/vignettes/jss1020.pdf)](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/texreg/vignettes/jss1020.pdf)?

Answer (score 3):

Section 5.5 of the package vignette offers a solution. The package vignette was published as an article in the Journal of Statistical Software. It can be found here: http://www.jstatsoft.org/v55/i08/.

More specifically, the robust standard errors and p values have to be extracted from your `result` matrix and handed over to `texreg` via the `override.se` and `override.pval` arguments:

```
se <- result[, 2]
pval <- result[, 4]
screenreg(    # display the results in the R console
    m, 
    omit.coef = "IDs", 
    override.se = se, 
    override.pval = pval
)
texreg(       # for LaTeX output
    m, 
    omit.coef = "IDs", 
    override.se = se, 
    override.pval = pval
)
```

Another way to do it would be to extract the coefficients from your original model, save them into a `texreg` object, manipulate this object, and then hand it over to the `texreg` function:

```
tr <- extract(m)
tr@pvalues <- result[, 4]
tr@se <- result[, 2]
screenreg(tr)  # or texreg including your original arguments...
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I'm getting a bug however:  I've followed the instructions in the paper and I'm getting the correct numerical tabular output, but the stars aren't being placed correctly where something is significant in the cl() output.  Any idea what might be causing this?

Comment: What is the output of `packageVersion("texreg")`?

Comment: Can you update to the latest version 1.29.7 and see if it works? It works here using this version. You can download it from http://r-forge.r-project.org/R/?group_id=1420 once the build process has finished. Did you follow the code presented above exactly? Did the second solution work for you?

Comment: Is there a way to do this when you want to put more than one regression together in the same table with texreg for Latex output?

Comment: Yes, you can submit multiple models wrapped in a list. The `override` arguments accept lists of vectors, with one numeric vector of standard errors or p-values per model.